# If value not found then add blank field in excel formula

Tags: excel, csv

I have text like this :

```
Baby Tula Explore Coast Carrier - Marble
Baby Tula Explore Coast Archer
```

What I have tried :

```
=TRIM(REPLACE(F20,1,FIND("-",F20),""))
```

If there are multiple dash in string, then it should return last dash after value.

Eg :

```
Skip Hop Easy-Serve Travel Bowl & Spoon- Grey/Soft Coral
Answer : Grey/Soft Coral
```

This above formula working for 1st string and return "**Marble**" but, for 2nd string it's return error.

I want to do like if not found then, it's not return error and remain blank field.

How to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap in in an `IFERROR` function. This function returns a value (blank in your case) if an error results from the formula inside it. Like this

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(REPLACE(F20,1,FIND("-",F20),"")), " ")
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: If There are two dash in string. Then, it should consider text from last dash. Then, how should I need to do?

Comment: So you only want to remove the second dash if there are two?

Comment: No. It should be get value after last dash. => Skip Hop Easy-Serve Travel Bowl & Spoon- Grey/Soft Coral
....... From this It should return "Grey/Soft Coral" because, it's last dash after value.

Comment: This is probably best if asked as a new question.

Comment: Edit your question by providing an example for both case. if there is 1 `-`wait do you want & if there are many what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))=0,"",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))),1))
)`

- Iif there is no `-` you will get nothing
- If there is/are `-` you will get the value after the last `-`